# Nested Transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directives `azContainer`, `azBody`, `azHeader` which placed as

```
<az-container az-header>
   <az-body></az-body>
</az-container
```

And `azContainer` uses *transclude*, but `azBody` also uses *transclude*, and when page gets rendered, i get this

```
<az-container>
    <az-header>_omited_</az-header>
    <az-container>
        <az-body>_omited_</az-body>
    </az-container>
</az-container>
```

And what was expected is

```
<az-container>
    <az-header>_omited_</az-header>
    <az-body>_omited_</az-body>
</az-container>
```

[Plnuker](http://plnkr.co/edit/umt8YLFalfRGcJf9IRaR?p=preview) Take a look at source. There is 2 `az-container`s. And couldnt find any source that explains my case. And also please provide consistent solution, as im going to nest very large amount of directives, maybe 4-6 nested tranclusions, <s>So that people at github wont throw at me tomatoes</s>

Simplified version [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/umt8YLFalfRGcJf9IRaR?p=preview)

Comment: Please provide a simplified demo with minimal html. We shouldn't have to look through numerous source files to see what your issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your azuredPageContent directive has azuredPageContainer.html as templateUrl, Im guessing it should be azuredPageContent.html.

Comment: thanks much, wasted 40minutes on that